Dynamically build a zip archive on AWS S3 using the Java SDK?
I currently have several thousands of objects on S3. Using a Spring service, the goal is to take a arbitrary list of object keys as an input and compile them into a zip archive in a separate folder in the same bucket for later download.
Building the zip locally is not an option, because the end size of the zip can be tens of GB. I have read through the AWS Java SDK docs and I don't see a way of building a zip dynamically. All of the put/upload functions want a set content length (which I don't have).
I essentially need a zip "placeholder" on S3 that I can stream to without having to keep the desired S3 objects in memory or on disk. How can I do this?

What I ended up doing is adding a class that extends OutputStream and creates a multi-part upload when the buffer reaches the set limit (in my case I set it to 10MB, AWS minimum is 5MB).
https://gist.github.com/mjohnston-vtx/411b417a5c4b4e053961acf719885085
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.AbortMultipartUploadRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompletedMultipartUpload;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompletedPart;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateMultipartUploadRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.UploadPartRequest;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Provides an OutputStream which uses the S3Client to support streaming large files directly to S3 without
 * needing to keep the object in local memory or storage.
 * <p>
 * <a href="https://gist.github.com/blagerweij/ad1dbb7ee2fff8bcffd372815ad310eb#file-s3outputstream-java">
 * Adapted for AWS SDK V2 from this Github Gist
 * </a>
 */
public class S3OutputStreamWrapper extends OutputStream {
    //10MB buffer is above the AWS minimum of 5MB for a part and should prevent having to make too many calls
    //https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html
    protected static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 10000000;

    private final S3Client s3Client;
    private final String bucket;
    private final String key;
    private final byte[] buf;
    private final List<String> partETags;

    private int bufferPos;
    private String uploadId;
    private boolean streamIsOpen;

    public S3OutputStreamWrapper(S3Client s3Client, String bucket, String key) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
        this.bucket = bucket;
        this.key = key;
        this.buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        this.bufferPos = 0;
        this.partETags = new ArrayList<>();
        this.streamIsOpen = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
        assertOpen();
        if (bufferPos >= buf.length) {
            flushBufferAndRewind();
        }
        buf[bufferPos++] = (byte) b;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NotNull byte[] bytes) {
        write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NotNull byte[] bytes, int o, int l) {
        assertOpen();

        var offset = o;
        var length = l;
        int size;
        while (length > (size = buf.length - bufferPos)) {
            System.arraycopy(bytes, offset, buf, bufferPos, size);
            bufferPos += size;
            offset += size;
            length -= size;
        }
        System.arraycopy(bytes, offset, buf, bufferPos, length);
        bufferPos += length;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void flush() {
        assertOpen();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (streamIsOpen) {
            streamIsOpen = false;
            if (null != uploadId) {
                if (bufferPos > 0) {
                    uploadPart();
                }

                var completedParts = new CompletedPart[partETags.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < partETags.size(); i++) {
                    completedParts[i] = CompletedPart.builder().eTag(partETags.get(i)).partNumber(i + 1).build();
                }
                s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(CompleteMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucket)
                    .key(key)
                    .uploadId(uploadId)
                    .multipartUpload(CompletedMultipartUpload.builder().parts(completedParts).build())
                    .build()
                );
            } else {
                s3Client.putObject(
                    PutObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket(bucket)
                        .key(key)
                        .contentLength(Integer.toUnsignedLong(bufferPos))
                        .build(),
                    RequestBody.fromInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf, 0, bufferPos), bufferPos)
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        streamIsOpen = false;
        if (null != uploadId) {
            s3Client.abortMultipartUpload(AbortMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucket).key(key).uploadId(uploadId).build()
            );
        }
    }

    protected void flushBufferAndRewind() {
        if (null == uploadId) {
            final var response = s3Client.createMultipartUpload(
                CreateMultipartUploadRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build()
            );

            if (response.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful()) {
                this.uploadId = response.uploadId();
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "[HTTP " + response.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode() + "] Failed to create multipart upload."
                );
            }
        }

        uploadPart();
        bufferPos = 0;
    }

    protected void uploadPart() {
        var response = s3Client.uploadPart(
            UploadPartRequest.builder()
                .uploadId(uploadId)
                .bucket(bucket)
                .key(key)
                .partNumber(partETags.size() + 1)
                .build(),
            RequestBody.fromInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf, 0, bufferPos), bufferPos)
        );
        partETags.add(response.eTag());
    }

    private void assertOpen() {
        if (!streamIsOpen) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stream is closed.");
        }
    }
}

This allows you to do GET requests for different objects and pipe them to this OutputStream:
var keyList = List.of("s3Key1", ...)
var zos = new ZipOutputStream(new S3OutputStreamWrapper(s3Client, bucketName, archiveKey));
for (var key : keyList) {
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(key));
    var imageBytes = s3Client.getObject(...).readAllBytes();
    zos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length)
    zos.closeEntry();
}
zos.close();

